# How can I fix this SQL error on this query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

```
DECLARE @providerIdList varchar(400)
DECLARE @q varchar(400)

SELECT @q  =  ''

SELECT @providerIdList = '(1, 5, 15)'


SET @q = 'SELECT u.Id FROM [user] u
    LEFT JOIN Provider p ON u.Provider_FK = p.Id
    LEFT JOIN  Providers2Users pu ON pu.user_FK = u.Id 
    LEFT JOIN Provider ap ON ap.Id = pu.provider_fk
    WHERE p.Id  IN ' + @providerIdList




exec @q
```

Here is the exception that I am getting when I tried to execute query shown above

---

```
Msg 203, Level 16, State 2, Line 18
The name 'SELECT u.Id FROM [user] u
    LEFT JOIN Provider p ON u.Provider_FK = p.Id
    LEFT JOIN  Providers2Users pu ON pu.user_FK = u.Id 
    LEFT JOIN Provider ap ON ap.Id = pu.provider_fk
    WHERE p.Id  IN (1, 5, 15)' is not a valid identifier.
```

---

I would really appreciate if somebody can point me the cause of these errors

Answer (score 8):

You're looking for [sp_executesql](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx).  Do this instead:

```
DECLARE @providerIdList nvarchar(400)
DECLARE @q nvarchar(400)

SELECT @q  =  N''

SELECT @providerIdList = N'(1, 5, 15)'


SET @q = N'SELECT u.Id FROM [user] u
    LEFT JOIN Provider p ON u.Provider_FK = p.Id
    LEFT JOIN  Providers2Users pu ON pu.user_FK = u.Id 
    LEFT JOIN Provider ap ON ap.Id = pu.provider_fk
    WHERE p.Id  IN ' + @providerIdList

exec sp_executesql @q
```

What you're doing now is trying to invoke the command as a stored procedure, which it's clearly not.  sp_executesql is a system stored procedure, which allows you to execute a valid SQL statement.  The system stored procedures are on the master database, FYI.

Comment: exec (@q) will also work. You just need to surround your @var in parenthesis

Comment: this will not work: Msg 214, Level 16, State 2, Procedure sp_executesql, Line 1
Procedure expects parameter '@statement' of type 'ntext/nchar/nvarchar'.

Comment: @KM: Fixed it to be nvarchar.  I forget this dependency of sp_executesql all the time.  As a rule, you should be using nvarchar, anyway, though. Don't assume ASCII will be able to cover all possible characters!

Answer (score 5):

You also can use

```
exec(@q)
```

this will execute the literal string.

The difference is in the parenthesis!

Comment: I'm not a fan of this method for readability reasons.  It makes it tough, especially when you have a stored proc calling a bunch of SQL and other stored procs.  Using sp_executesql keeps these separate enough, at least for me.  But, that's just my preference.

Comment: Eric, I agree, but for me it's easier to remember, sometimes I forget sp_executesql.

Answer (score 0):

your trying to execute a stored procedure @q, which is not valid, use:

```
execute (@q)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok make sure you use NVARCHAR not VARCHAR. Just then you might use `EXEC sp_executesql @q`.

Answer (score 0):

declare @params NVARCHAR(4000)
declare @sql NVARCHAR(4000)

SET @providerIdList = '(1, 5, 15)'

SET @sql = 'SELECT u.Id FROM [user] u    LEFT JOIN Provider p ON u.Provider_FK = p.Id    LEFT JOIN  Providers2Users pu ON pu.user_FK = u.Id     LEFT JOIN Provider ap ON ap.Id = pu.provider_fk    WHERE p.Id  IN ' + @providerIdList'

SELECT @params = N'@providerIdList VARCHAR OUTPUT'

exec sp_executesql @sql, @params,@providerIdList=@providerIdList

Answer (score 0):

Or given what you show as your code, I wouldn't use dynamic SQL at all. Dynamic SQl should be avoided if possible.

```
SELECT u.Id FROM [user] u    
LEFT JOIN Provider p ON u.Provider_FK = p.Id    
LEFT JOIN  Providers2Users pu ON pu.user_FK = u.Id     
LEFT JOIN Provider ap ON ap.Id = pu.provider_fk    
WHERE p.Id  IN (1, 5, 15)
```